# Is it possible to use a UI kit in React native with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to load a UI Kit to skip the whole process of building UI components by myself. (Even though, yes, I'm new to react-native).

But here comes the problem, after doing the `npm install` and importing it:

`import { View, TextInput, Button } from 'galio-framework'` I get a:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'galio-framework'. '/Users/user/FirstApp/node_modules/galio-framework/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/galio-framework` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'galio-framework';`
```

I've tried to `npm install @types/galio-framework` but it gets me a not found.

In the simulator, it tells me to check the render method of `App`.

How can I run it? Is it even possible to run it with Expo?

my `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^1.2.0",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "galio-framework": "^0.6.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your `package.json`

Comment: @dglozano there ya go, edited.